# minecraft colored signs (§,{Color:"blue"})

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

how can you put color on signs?,tried the color symbol (§) but it did not copy.
also tried NBT tags such as {Color:"blue"} and it did not work ):!

Answer (score 3):

To add colors on signs you need to use the JSON format. The correct way to make colored text in Minecraft with JSON is this:

```
 {"text":"foo","color":"blue"}
```

Where "foo" is the actual displayed text, and "blue" can be any of the 16 [official color names,](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes#Color_codes) with an underscore instead of a space.

However you cannot just type this directly into the sign (it would be too long, for one thing). You need to use the /blockdata command. The command to edit a sign's text is this:

```
/blockdata X Y Z {Text1:"foo",Text2:"foo",Text3:"foo",Text4:"foo"}
```

Where Text1-4 are the different lines, foo is the displayed text, and X Y Z are the sign's coordinates.

To put the JSON into this command we will need to use a backslash to "escape" all of the quotation marks in the JSON string, so that it can all be read as one string and it doesn't mess up the NBT data format, like this:

```
 {\"text\":\"foo\",\"color\":\"blue\"}
```

And finally, the command to add a blue foo to line two is this:

```
/blockdata X Y Z {Text2:"{\"text\":\"foo\",\"color\":\"blue\"}"}
```

Comment: good! I will try that. tag:minecraft